# Wordpress show content after submitted form values are checked

Tags: wordpress, forms, submit

What i'm trying to do is to protect a page's content using a meta-field.
I have a form in front-end with a password and one submit button.
The password is stored as meta-field in the particular page.
if the front-end submitted password matches, show the content of the page.
Here's what's so far and not working:

```
  <?php if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
   $password = $_POST['pwd'];
   $fieldvalue =  get_post_meta($this_page_id, 'password', true);

   if($password== $fieldvalue)
   {
     the_content();
   }
  }
  ?>
```

the wordpress given way to add password is not working correctly for me.
Any ideas on this one?

Comment: *wordpress given way to add password is not working correctly for me* : can you briefly describe what's exactly happening when you set the visibility of the page to "Password protected"?

Comment: It doesn't protect the content.Content is shown no matter what.I don't if there is something that needs to be added to my template file which is custom.

Comment: Does the page that you are trying to protect use a custom template? If so can you make it use the default template and see if built-in password protection works?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following code to your page's template

```
<?php
  if ( !post_password_required($post) ) {
    echo 'protected content';
  } else {
    the_content();
  }
?>
```

Here's the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_password_required) link : *Whether post requires password and correct password has been provided.*

Comment: Still not working....after i put my password, i don't view the content  i see the echoed message "protected content".

Comment: Got it to work! It needed a      if ( !post_password_required($post) ) { echo the_content(); }